# UITextField Selector Function Not Being Called iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I created a textField configured simple, but my action function won't be called for some reason no idea why (i.e. my breakpoint won't even get hit)

TextField code:

```
lazy var inputField: UITextField = {
   let textField = UITextField()
    textField.borderStyle = .none
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    
    let paddingView = UIView()
    paddingView.setDimensions(height: 50, width: 28)
    textField.leftView = paddingView
    textField.leftViewMode = .always
    
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleUpdateUseerInfo), for: .editingDidEnd)
    
    return textField
}()
```

Action func code:

```
@objc
func handleUpdateUseerInfo(sender: UITextField) {
    guard let valeu = sender.text else { return }
    delegate?.settingsCell(self, wantsToUpdateUserWith: valeu, for: viewModel.section)
}
```

Comment: please put the correct tags for your question - it has nothing to do with `r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s an update with the new Xcode and swift. Whenever you have addSubview(), replace it with contentView.addSubview()

Answer (score 0):

The selector if probably in wrong format. Try replacing this line:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleUpdateUseerInfo), for: .editingDidEnd)
```

With this:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleUpdateUseerInfo(sender:)), for: .editingDidEnd)
```